# NoSQL data split

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql

I am new in NoSQL systems. I want to use Java+Spring+MongoDB (not important). 
I try to build correct scheme for my data. I'll have too much log records (something about 3 000 000 000 per year). Record structure looks like this:

```
{
    shop: 'shop1',
    product: 'product1',
    count: '10',
    incost: '100',
    outcost: '120',
    operation: 'sell',
    date: '2015-12-12'
}
```

I have about 1000 shops and about 30000 products.

I should have reports with sum of count or sum of (sum*(outcost-incost)) by [shops]+product splited by days or months.

*[shops] means optional filter. In this case (without shops) performance is not matter.

*Reports older than 1 year may be required but performance is not matter.

Can i use single collection "logs" with indexes on date, shop, product. Or i should split this collection to subcollections by shops and years explicitly?

Sorry if my question is stupid, i am just beginner...

Regards, 
Minas

Answer (score 0):

Unless and until the document grows further, this works fine. In case, if you want to add more fields to the existing document or append the existing fields and if you think it may grow beyond 16 MB, then its better to have separate collections.

Indexing keys also appear to be fine as you are having compound index on shop, date and product fields.

You would be having some performance gain(easy and fast as only single disk seek happens), if complete data is retrieved from single collection rather fetched from multiple collections.

Answer (score 0):

I would not do much aggregation on the main collection, 3 billion records is quite a lot.

One massive problem I can think with this is that any query will likely be huge, returning a massive number of documents. Now, it is true that you can mitigate most negative factors of querying this collection by using sharding to spread out the weight of the data itself, however, the sheer amount of data returned to the `mongos` will likely be slow and painful.

There comes a time when no amount of index will save you because your collection is just too darn big.

This would not matter if you was just displaying the collection, MongoDB could do that easily, it is aggregation that will not work well.

I would do as you suggest: pre-aggregate into other collections based on data fragments and time buckets.